# label name and background color for dropdownButton

Tags: css, dojo

I **want to display the** **label name on bottom of the image**, Currently label is displayed on the right hand side of the image on DropDownButton.
Another requirement is i **have to remove the background color of the dropdown button**, it should be seen as plain image but not button and when user clicks on the image submenu items should be shown as displayed in http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/361/.
I have overridden below css code to remove the background color for the dropdown menu so that it looks only as plain image but didn't worked. 
Please suggest. Thanks.

```
.claro .dijitButton .dijitButtonNode,
.claro .dijitDropDownButton .dijitButtonNode,
.claro .dijitComboButton .dijitButtonNode,
.claro .dijitToggleButton .dijitButtonNode {

  border: 0px solid #759dc0;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  color: #000000; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want to display the label name on bottom of the image**

You can make the elements with class `.dijitButtonText` `display:block` which will make it display at the bottom of the image.

**background color of the dropdown button**

Are you referring to the red background color on the image? If so the red color is part of the image so you would have to edit the image to remove the red background color.

Hope that helps.

Example of the text at the bottom of the image and the background-image removed (not the red color in the icon background).

http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/363/